# Functions as the struct fields or as struct methods

Tags: function, go, methods, struct

Could anybody help me to clarify in which situations is better to use functions as the struct fields and when as the methods of struct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A field of function type is **not** a method, so it's not part of the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the struct type. A "true" method declared with the struct type as the receiver will be part of the method set.

That being said, if you want to implement an interface, you have no choice but to define "true" methods.

Methods are "attached" to concrete types and cannot be changed at runtime. A field of function type may be used to "mimic" virtual methods, but as said above, this is not a method. A field of function type may be reassigned at runtime.

Like in this example:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar func()
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{
        Bar: func() { fmt.Println("initial") },
    }
    f.Bar()

    f.Bar = func() { fmt.Println("changed") }
    f.Bar()
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qmnLhNuh-3r)):

```
initial
changed
```

Fields of function type are often used to store callback functions. Examples from the standard lib are  [`http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) and [`http.Transport`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport).