# Can I have a function inside my struct? Converting from PHP class

Tags: php, function, go, struct

I have some php code which I'm trying to migrate to Golang code. This is it:

Code in PHP:

```
class AuditProcessor {
    public function __construct( BfsBlockChain $Bfs ) 
    {
        $this->bfs = $bfs;
    }
```

I know this is a class, and there is a function inside of it. My question is: in Golang, can I have a function inside my struct? Or how can I replace the code, or format it?

Comment: Please take some time to walk through [the introduction tour of go](https://go.dev/tour/), methods and function types are covered relatively early on [here](https://go.dev/tour/methods/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can have fields of [function type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_types), and you can also have [methods](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_declarations). To fields you can assign any function values (with matching signature), methods are not changeable.

For example:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar func() // This is a regular field of function type
}

func (f Foo) Baz() { // This is a method of Foo
    fmt.Println("I'm Baz()")
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    f := Foo{
        Bar: func() { fmt.Println("I'm Bar()") },
    }

    f.Bar()
    f.Baz()

    f.Bar = Bar2
    f.Bar()
}

func Bar2() {
    fmt.Println("I'm Bar2()")
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/9NgMzFDvD0M)):

```
I'm Bar()
I'm Baz()
I'm Bar2()
```

See related: [Functions as the struct fields or as struct methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224523/functions-as-the-struct-fields-or-as-struct-methods/66224586#66224586)